# asp.net MVC Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

I found the tutorial to implement Bootstrap datepicker. But I have problems to get it working.

My BoundleConfig

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  //Galerija JS
            /*"~/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js",*/
            "~/Scripts/bootsrtap-popup.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/moment.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/respond.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-colorpicker.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.icheck.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/select2.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/unicorn.form_common.js",
            "~/Scripts/unicorn.form_validation.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
            "~/Scripts/unicorn.jui.js",
            "~/Scripts/excanvas.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
            /*"~/Scripts/jquery-ui.custom.js",*/
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.resize.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/unicorn.js",
            "~/Scripts/unicorn.dashboard.js",
            "~/Scripts/excanvas.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.flot.resize.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.sparkline.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/jquery.nicescroll.min.js",
            "~/Scripts/unicorn.dashboard.js",
            "~/Scripts/unicorn.js"/*,
            "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"*/));


  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/jquery-ui.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/colorpicker.css",
            "~/Content/datepicker.css",
            "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
            "~/Content/fullcalendar.css",
            "~/Content/icheck/flat/blue.css",
            "~/Content/jquery.jscrollpane.css",
            "~/Content/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css",
            "~/Content/select2.css",
            "~/Content/unicorn.css",
            "~/Content/glyphicons.css"/*,
            "~/Content/unicorn.ie7.css",*/

            /*"~/Content/unicorn-login.css"*/
            /*"~/Content/prettyPhoto.css",*/
            /*"~/Content/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css",*/
            /*"~/Content/bootstrap-glyphicons.css"*/
            /*"~/Content/HomeStyles.css"*/));
    }
```

Then I have in my layout:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - PORTAL PGD</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

And:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

In my wiew page:

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatumRojstva, new
                           {
                               @class = "help-block text-left"
                           })
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.DatumRojstva, new {
            htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }     })

                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DatumRojstva)
                            </div>
```

And the render sections part:

```
@section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#DatumRojstva').datepicker();
        });
</script>
}
```

I tried to follow different tutorials but I can't find the correct way to get my datepicker working. I tried to implement this solution http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/
I suspect that the problem is in the bundle config but I can't find where.

http://scottusa-001-site1.myasp.net/BPB/Home/ClaniDodaj

This is the page where we can find my datepicker.

Comment: Which datepicker do you want - the jquery-ui or the bootstrap one (your including both) and `~/bundles/bootstrap` is including duplicates of the files you have already added in the previous bundles.

Comment: I would need the bootstrap datepicker or if I am specific I would need the datetimepricker.

Comment: What is your browser and what is exactly " problems to get it working."?

Comment: I use Firefox and Chrome. I can't get the datepicker to open and chose the date.
All I get is http://shrani.si/f/q/vK/Hg1r5R0/1.jpg

Comment: With jQueryUI js files inside your Scripts folder, this code should work. Are you getting any script error ? Check your browser console.

Comment: I don't get any script errors.